# Copy SQL MDF file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, database-backups

I'm trying to get a copy of an MDF file but coming across the standard "file is in use" message which I believe is the SQL service holding a lock on it. Is it possible to make a copy of the mdf file without having to stop the service or in any way affect users/applications?

If not, is it possible to create a once-off full backup mdf to a different location than the existing one so that it wouldn't be locked by SQL service?

*(Variations on this have been asked on this site already, but I don't think this is a duplicate. I am not trying to relocate the database, simply attempting to take a copy of the mdf - without interrupting Live operations - so I can place it on my dev machine at home and play around with the database)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will let u make a backup :

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabase TO DISK = 'W:\DBs\MyDatabase.bak' WITH INIT;
```

and if u want to backup the log file as well then just add this command **before** the previous one :

`ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET RECOVERY FULL;`

Then if you want to recover the database from the backup file try this command:

```
USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase 
SET SINGLE_USER WITH
ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
-- The previous command will used to close all connections to the database
-- until you recover it

Restore Database MyDatabase From Disk = 'W:\DBs\MyDatabase.bak' WITH REPLACE;

ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET MULTI_USER
-- This will reopen the database for users connections
```

Comment: Will this change anything on Live settings? I'm worried about anything like this altering the current backup settings/procedure, and seeing stuff like ALTER DATABASE makes me nervous!

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: I would only be using the BACKUP DATABASE command. I am assuming the .bak path is pointing to a new file/location different from current scheduled backup routine (which is mdf anyway) and that running that is completely independent of the regular backup routine, and in no way affects it. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right and if you don't want to change the backup settings then just don't run the Alter code just run the backup code

Comment: Did the job and normal backups are running. Thanks, was good to get confirmation that I wouldn't interfere with Live system.